# tableView.selectRow has no effect when called within a UIContextualAction callback

Tags: swift, uikit, tableview

When calling `selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` inside a `UIContextualAction` callback, nothing changes: the specified row doesn't turn gray.

Here's the simplest code I could write that exhibits the issue:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { _, _, callback in
        tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        callback(true)
    }

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

I tried many variations:

- properly performing the delete operation (updating the model then updating the table view with `deleteRows()`)
- not animating the selection operation
- using a `.normal` action instead of a `.destructive` one
- grouping various parts of the callback code in a `tableView.performBatchUpdates()` block
- calling all of these methods in various orders, inside and outside the `performBatchUpdates()` call
- somehow waiting for the end of the deletion animation with `CATransaction.setCompletionBlock()`
- dispatching the selection operation on the main queue to have it execute a smidge later

All without success.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of a delete action, you can implement the `tableView(tableView: cell: indexPath:)` delegate method, and perform the selection there; make sure to check that the cell didn't simply scroll off-screen, though.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cellWasBeingDeleted(cell) { // your own implementation
        tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One makeshift way to have the selection operation succeed is to use a timer, in order to call `selectRow()` after the deletion animation is finished:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { _, _, callback in
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { _ in
            tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
        callback(true)
    }

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

This is obviously far from a clean solution, since it depends on the timing of the animation not changing in future iOS releases, and requires writing extra code to make sure the selection operation is still relevant 0.5 seconds later, when the timer fires (which I didn't do in this sample).